# iPhone - how to free up space when storage is completely full

Tags: iphone

My mom has an iPhone 4 (or 4S) and she has taken so many photos that there are 0 Bytes space left.

I can't install apps to delete files on the phone directly.
I can't move files via USB.
I can't delete files via USB.

Windows 7 shows the "Deleting ..." window but nothing happens (not even on a single photo).

So how can I delete all those photos (backups done) or even better the whole phone including iOS?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the option of **"Erase all content and settings"**. It's an option provided by Apple to delete your content and reset the iPhone to factory settings. 
This [link](https://support.apple.com/en-ap/HT201274) will help you safely do that. Just make sure it's fully charged and connected to the charger.

Comment: Sure. Try it and if it doesn't work as you want then try "Factory Reset". But I think it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If there are many apps installed from the Ap Store (or iTunes store) it may be possible to delete some of them to get enough extra space to be able to delete photos. After deleting photos any of the apps you deleted could then be reinstalled from their original store at no charge. (If this works, the only possible problem could be if any of the deleted apps aren't current since reinstalling them would bring in the current version which *might* work differently.)

If the problem with deleting photos is dependent on the app you are using to try to delete photos this may work; if it's a problem with lack of space for iOS itself then you'll probably just have the same problem trying to delete apps, too. It can't hurt to try. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can backup important data on iCloud, then you can try to erase your iPhone, tap Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings. Before erasing iPhone, connect your device to a charger and leave it connected until your device resets.

Comment: Backups is very important. You should be attentive.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution is very simple: sign out icloud account, and sign in again. That's all.