# The Storage "Used" does not add up

Tags: ios, memory, storage, iphone

I have iPhone 6s 64GB. I got 64GB because 16GB just wasn't cutting it. I didn't want to worry about memory being full. However last night out of nowhere, I got the message saying my storage is almost full.

Confused, because there was no way I used 55GB(actual storage) of space. So I headed over to my Manage Storage page, which had me even more confused.

[image]

As you can see, the apps that take up the most space are Photos, Spotify and Music. They don't even take up 10GB.. I added the Used storage by all the other apps and it does not even come close to 45GB. When I plug in my phone to my laptop, it says the storage is used by Documents & Data.

Before you answer my question, I am aware that Safari and Chrome take up cookies and cache. I am also aware that other apps can have similar data. Even considering all that, there is just no way I am using 52GB.

Just what is going on?

Comment: A bit (lot?) late, but apps also take up storage for their code and resources.

Answer (score 1):

I had something like this on my iPad. It turned out that when I streamed (rather than download to watch later) movies and TV shows it stored the data on the device but didn't report it.

What I had to do what log out of iTunes/iCloud and log back in again, this cleared all these cached movies and released the data back to me.

Answer (score 0):

There are just too many things that require physical storage. That's why Apple chose to lump a lot of things into the "Other" category. it's seems like your phone is filled with cached files and data. That can include:

- Documents & Data
- Safari browsing data
- Mail data
- iTunes data, including files that have been streamed (which can be BIG).
  ...

Deleting data, and then restoring is a good way, but you should back up first. or it will cause data lost.

You said that you have many photos storage, have you checked your "Recently deleted" album? Maybe it takes up your storage. Since iOS 8, the pics and videos you deleted are not actually gone. If you want to make them disappeared you need to go to the "Recently deleted" album and delete them again. Otherwise you need to wait for 30 days they will be deleted automatically.

In addition, you can try to clean up cache files frequently. someone who has similar situation with you, You can also refer to [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229119/iphone-how-to-free-up-space-when-storage-is-completely-full).